# Withdraw command not executing

Tags: php

Everytime I try to withdraw my bitcoin to test it out the withdraw feature, I have come across an error that I don't really understand.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem.

My website is http://freebitcoinfaucet.xyz if this helps.

// Run the `SQL` against the `PDO connection`. Then we can calculate the time it
        // took to execute and log the query `SQL`, bindings and time in our memory.

```
try {
        $result = $callback($query, $bindings);
    }

    // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new QueryException(
            $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
        );
    }

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Log a query in the connection's query log.
 *
 * @param  string  $query
 * @param  array   $bindings
 * @param  float|null  $time
 * @return void
 */
```

This is the argument!

"

> SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value
>   for column 'net_amount' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `withdraws`
>   (`transaction_id`, `user_id`, `gateway_name`, `amount`, `charge`,
>   `net_amount`, `status`, `account`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values
>   (8QmVNU7nCA0k2, 7, BitCoin, 0.00000100, 7.000000025, -6.999999025, 0,
>   3DPS7Mwz5E4p4KuooykCB8h6GhHwnWH2v6, 2018-10-18 00:28:10, 2018-10-18
>   00:28:10))

Comment: on your database, what net_amount set on?

Comment: I'd bet your `net_amount` field is an unsigned (i.e. positive-only) numeric field. Make sure it's not an integer, too, if you're storing decimal data.

Comment: Name: Net_Amount Type: Decimal Lenth/Value: 15,8 Attributes:unsigned

Comment: That's your issue. See the duplicate thread.